# Partial preparation of stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement

I have a MySQL stored procedure which takes three parameters.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("CALL MyStoredProce(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iss',$id,$category,$name);
```

In one case, only one two parameters are changing. Can I make partial preparation like (where middle parameter will be constant in this preparation):

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("CALL MyStoredProc(?,'CARS',?)");
$stmt->bind_param('is',$id,$name);
```

Maybe there could be some benefits for DBMS to prepare statements with less expected variations in parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare` action creates an "execution plan," which is the step-by-step series of operations that the engine actually carries out.  This need happen only once, no matter how many times the statement is subsequently *executed.*

(The `EXPLAIN` verb will print out this execution plan in quasi-readable form. It is *quite* interesting ...)

Because the SQL contained three `?` placeholders, the execution plan stipulates that three parameters must be supplied anytime the statement is executed.

"Binding" is the process by which you specify what values shall be associated with each of the parameters needed, and this takes place each time the prepared statement is *executed.*  It has nothing at all to do with the `prepare` step.

---

*Incidentally:*   it is irrelevant that the SQL query in this case consists of a call to a stored procedure. What I've said applies to any SQL statement.

Comment: OK, I know what you said about explain plan is general of how query preparation works in database. But I think that here it is not irrelevant that in my statement preparation a call is to stored procedure because I would be able to create prepared statement for query like `INSERT INTO services(id,category,name) VALUES(?,'CARS',?)`or I'm wrong (I have to check).

Comment: What I *meant,* in my parenthetical comment, is that what I said applies equally to *any* query. In other words, it would apply exactly-the-same to an query that consisted of `INSERT INTO ...`, as it would to a query that consisted of `CALL ...`. This is a ***client**-side* step in which the 'query optimizer' turns an SQL-string ... "any string, every string" ... into a plan of action.  You are absolutely correct that you can "create a prepared statement" for anything-at-all. I suppose that what I really meant to 'clarify(??)' is that it would have no impact whatsoever on: *the stored proc."